# Specify the name of a property in an anonymous type?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, extension-methods, anonymous-types

In web api, I'm returning anonymous types like so:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new
{
    SomeNameHere = new {Message = "my message"}
});
```

I'm trying to write an extension method like this:

```
public static class RequestExtensions
    {
        public static HttpResponseMessage CreateMyResponse(
            this HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage,
            HttpStatusCode statusCode, 
            string wrapper, 
            string message)
        {
            return httpRequestMessage.CreateResponse(statusCode, new
            {
                wrapper = new
                {
                    Message = message
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

It would be called like this:

```
return Request.CreateMyResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "SomeCommand", "some message");
```

However, when I run this and test the endpoint in postman this is what I get back:

> {   "wrapper": {
>       "Message": "some message"   } }

I understand why this doesn't work, I'm just trying to find an alternate solution that would properly return this instead:

> {   "SomeCommand": {
>       "Message": "some message"   } }

I realize I could go make this object and return it that way, however I don't want to create a whole bunch of new objects for one time use like this. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like using an ExpandoObject will work!

```
public static HttpResponseMessage CreateWrappedResponse(
    this HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage,
    HttpStatusCode statusCode,
    string rootTagName,
    string message)
{
    dynamic messageObject = new ExpandoObject();
    dynamic wrapperObject = new ExpandoObject();

    var messageDictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)messageObject;
    messageDictionary.Add("Message", message);
    var wrapperDictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)wrapperObject;
    wrapperDictionary.Add(rootTagName, messageDictionary);

    return httpRequestMessage.CreateResponse(statusCode, wrapperDictionary);
}
```

And I can call the extension method like this:

```
return Request.CreateWrappedResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "SomeCommand", "some message");
```

And this will return my json in postman like I wanted:

> { "SomeCommand": { "Message": "some message" } }